Why does a magnet attract iron objects?
I am studying magnetism right now and I can’t understand how does a magnet work. I read that the magnet has a magnet field, which influences only charged particles with velocity. But then how does magnet attracts some metal objects, e.g iron nail? I read that in most metals there are free electrons, which are moving outside of the atom shells. But the average velocity component of these electrons in any direction is zero, so then the magnetic force is also zero…
At all I want to design my own musical instrument, which uses only magnets and no electricity. So I tried to determine how a magnet would act on a steel guitar string eg. and what forces are acting in this configuration.
P.S.: Can someone say what is the direction and magnitude of the force with which a magnet attracts a given object depending on the characteristics of the object, magnet, the environment and their mutual location.

"At all I want to design my own musical instrument, which uses only magnets and no electricity. " ... no chance, if taken literately. Electric and magnetic forces are interwoven. Another aspect is what you apply to your newly invented instrument. You can use magnets without (directly) using electric current (batteries etc. ). Looking at the answers so far and thinking twice, I myself don't know how a magnet works, even less after looking at the answers.

MAGNETS: How Do They Work?

A magnet does not attract all metals. It attracts materials that are ferromagnetic. These are materials that become magnetized themselves in the presence of a magnetic field. In such a magnetic field, they become magnetized in such a way that their "north pole" is closest to the original magnet's south pole, and vice-versa.
Some of the ferromagnetic material lose virtually all their magnetism when the original magnetic field is removed. Others retain some or even most of the magnetization they took on.

Electrons have a property called 'spin', which is similar to spin orbital angular momentum, i.e. the angular momentum that an object has by spinning around its axis. Any particle with non-zero spin has a magnetic moment. You could think of the electron as a ball of rotating charge, which has a magnetic field associated with it. This is not physically what's happening (electrons are point particles and have no size), but it might clear things up a bit.
Iron has an unpaired electron in its outer shell, which causes each iron atom to have a net magnetic moment. These magnetic moments can either all align (ferromagnetism) or all anti-align (antiferromagnetism). The latter means that the spins in neighbouring atoms alternate between pointing in one direction, or another direction. The magnetic dipole interaction wants to anti-align the spins: this is similar to how magnets want to anti-align when put next to each other. The other force is the exchange interaction. This is a quantum mechanical and is hard to explain, but it boils down to the fact that when neighbouring atoms align they are able to distribute their electrons better and this lowers the energy.
In ferromagnets the exchange interaction wins: the atoms align their spins and a net magnetic field results.
For your last paragraph: conductive metals react to magnetic fields by producing eddy currents. The result of this is that a magnet and a conductor "try to match velocity". If throw a magnet at a copper plate it will quickly slow down. Look on youtube for "eddy current demo" to see many wonderful videos on this effect.

‘ Iron has an unpaired electron in its outer shell’ In fact, iron has 5 unpaired electrons in its 3d shell, which is not the outer shell. The 5 spins are parallel.

Electrons have the property of being magnetic dipoles. To be precise, they are both electric charges and magnetic dipoles. Both are intrinsic properties with constant values.
Iron has unpaired electrons in its outer shell. These electrons can be easily aligned by an external magnetic field. As a result, iron has a macroscopic magnetic moment.
With a strong external magnet, the alignment of the iron electrons can be so strong that the net magnetic moment is maintained for some time even after the external field has been removed, i.e. it is self-retaining. However, the atomic oscillations that are always present (depending on the temperature of the body) destroy the magnetic dipole alignment of the electrons and the body returns to a uniform spatial distribution of the direction of its dipoles.
Incidentally, with a sufficiently strong magnetic field, all materials are influenced by this magnetic field. Then the external field also "tugs" at the paired alignment of the electrons and twists their magnetic dipoles. This can even make a frog float in a magnetic field.
